# How to create a url to start session in magento 2 (customer)

Tags: magento2, customer, url, login, session

The URL should be something like this:
**http://mymagento.store/customer/1dsd24343sd34** 
Pasting this url in any browser the customer should log in automatically

Answer (score 1):

Create your custom module a route with frontname  autologin .
Create a Index controller and index action in index action get hash from request param.
Decode hash and add login script something like below

```
protected $_customer; 
protected $_customerSession; 
public function _construct(...    
\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer,
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession) { ... 
 $this->_customer = $customer; 
 $this->_customerSession = $customerSession; ... 
}
```

Execute function will be something like :

```
$hash=$this->getRequest()->getParam('hash');
$email= /*write code for getting email*/;
$_customer->loadByEmail($email);

$this->_customerSession->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
```

Comment: thanks for answering, is it necessary that this hash be found in a table in the database?

Comment: If it is possible to decode hash then no need to save it.otherwise you can save it in db.